# Index of columns where rows match criterion Python Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have data from an Excel file in the format

```
0,1,0
1,0,0
0,0,1
```

I want to convert those data into a list where the `i`th element indicates the position of the nonzero element for the `i`th row. For example, the above would be:

```
 [1,0,2]
```

I tried two ways to no avail:

**Way one (NumPy)**

```
df = pd.read_excel(file,convert_float=False)
idx = np.where(df==1)[1]
```

This gives me an odd error- idx is never the same length as the number of row in df. For this data set the two numbers are always equal. (I double checked, and there are no empty rows.)

**Way two (Pandas)**

```
  idx = df.where(df==1)
```

This gives me output like:

```
 52     NaN      NaN      NaN 
 53        1      NaN      NaN 
 54        1      NaN      NaN
```

This is the appropriate shape, **but I don't know how to just get the column index**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]))
```

Use `np.argwhere` to find the element indices:

```
np.argwhere(df.values ==1)
```

returns:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

so for row 0 the column 1 contains 1 for the df:

```
    0   1   2
 0  0   1   0
 1  1   0   0
 2  0   0   1
```

Note:

(you can get just the column index  by using: `np.array_split(indices, 2,1)[1]` for example)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works for limited use cases including this one. If you know that you will only have a single `1` in your row, then you can transpose the original data frame so the indices of your columns from the original data frame become the row indices of the transposed data frame. With that you can find the max value in each row and return an array of those values.

Your original data frame is not the best example for this solution because it is symmetrical and its transpose is the same as the original data frame. So for the sake of this solution we'll use a starting data frame that looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:[0,0,1], 1:[1,0,0], 2:[0,1,0]})

# original data frame --> df
   0  1  2
0  0  1  0
1  0  0  1
2  1  0  0

# transposed data frame --> df.T
   0  1  2
0  0  0  1
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
```

Now to find the max of each row:

```
np.array(df.T.idxmax())
```

Which returns an array of values that represent the column indices of the original data frame that contain a 1:

```
[1 2 0]
```